# dplyr - Group by and select TOP x %

Tags: r, dplyr

Using the package dplyr and the function `sample_frac` it is possible to sample a percentage from every group. What I need is to first sort the elements in every group and then select top x% from every group?

There is a function `top_n`, but here I can only determine the number of rows, and I need a relative value.

For example the following data is grouped by gear and sorted by `wt` within each group:

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>%
  select(gear, wt) %>%
  group_by(gear) %>%
  arrange(gear, wt)

    gear    wt
1   3   2.465
2   3   3.215
3   3   3.435
4   3   3.440
5   3   3.460
6   3   3.520
7   3   3.570
8   3   3.730
9   3   3.780
10  3   3.840
11  3   3.845
12  3   4.070
13  3   5.250
14  3   5.345
15  3   5.424
16  4   1.615
17  4   1.835
18  4   1.935
19  4   2.200
20  4   2.320
21  4   2.620
22  4   2.780
23  4   2.875
24  4   3.150
25  4   3.190
26  4   3.440
27  4   3.440
28  5   1.513
29  5   2.140
30  5   2.770
31  5   3.170
32  5   3.570
```

Now I would like to select top 20 % within each gear group.

It would be very nice if the solution could be integrated with dplyr's `group_by` function.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Couldn't you just calculate the percentage yourself? I'm not sure if this works since we don't have a reproducible example, but I think it might: `my_data %>% group_by(my_var) %>% arrange(my_var) %>% filter(top_n()/n() == x%)`

Comment: @brittenb Thanks for ypur help! `top_n()` cannot be used without arguments.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Or another option with dplyr:

```
mtcars %>% select(gear, wt) %>% 
  group_by(gear) %>% 
  arrange(gear, desc(wt)) %>% 
  filter(wt > quantile(wt, .8))

Source: local data frame [7 x 2]
Groups: gear [3]

   gear    wt
  (dbl) (dbl)
1     3 5.424
2     3 5.345
3     3 5.250
4     4 3.440
5     4 3.440
6     4 3.190
7     5 3.570
```

Comment: Really creative solutions guys! Thanks a lot! :-)

Comment: I will join the majority and accept your answer :-)

Answer (score 9):

Here's another way

```
mtcars %>% 
  select(gear, wt) %>% 
  arrange(gear, desc(wt)) %>% 
  group_by(gear) %>% 
  slice(seq(n()*.2))

   gear    wt
  (dbl) (dbl)
1     3 5.424
2     3 5.345
3     3 5.250
4     4 3.440
5     4 3.440
6     5 3.570
```

I take "top" to mean "having the highest value for `wt`" and so used `desc()`.

Comment: I should be able to write `top_n(n()*.2)` in place of the `slice`, but alas, the familiar `Error in n() : This function should not be called directly` rears its head.

Answer (score 5):

I believe this gets to the answer you're looking for.

```
library(dplyr)

mtcars %>% select(gear, wt) %>% 
  group_by(gear) %>% 
  arrange(gear, wt) %>% 
  filter(row_number() / n() <= .2)
```

Comment: perfect! I think in `dplyr` there shoul be a function which implements this.

Comment: Just keep in mind that this approach doesn't allow for an "at least 20%" approach. What I mean by that is that if a group has 4 rows or less, then it will not select any of them because the minimum ratio will be greater than 20%. So keep in mind that you can lose data like this.

Comment: @brittenb How about `filter(row_number() <= max(1,.2*n()))` if you always want to keep at least one row?

Comment: @Frank I think that's a good idea if you're concerned with keeping at least one record from a group. It would obviously depend on the context of the problem, which is outside the scope of this question, but I just wanted to bring it up.

Answer (score 4):

I know this is coming late, but might help someone now. dplyr has a new function top_frac

```
  library(dplyr)
mtcars %>%
  select(gear, wt) %>%
  group_by(gear) %>%
  arrange(gear, wt) %>%
  top_frac(n = 0.2,wt = wt)
```

Here n is the fraction of rows to return and wt is the variable to be used for ordering.

The output is as below.

`gear wt
3   5.250
3   5.345
3   5.424

4   3.440
4   3.440
5   3.570`

Answer (score 0):

A slight variation using top_n and dplyr:

```
mtcars %>% 
 group_by(gear) %>% 
 select(gear, wt) %>% 
 arrange(gear) %>% 
 top_n(seq(n()*.2))

  gear    wt
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     3  5.42
2     3  5.34
3     3  5.25
4     4  3.44
5     4  3.44
6     5  3.57
```