# How do I get the bottom 10% of values in a dataframe column?

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I have a dataframe (`allDat`) that looks like the following (but more rows) and I'm trying to subset it to get individuals (samples) with the bottom 10% of Expression:

```
SampleID    Expression   Gene
HSB496      14.64295     ENSG00000118271
HSB261      14.3346      ENSG00000144820
HSB248      13.48286     ENSG00000167552
```

Here is what I have tried, but I feel like this is wrong or that there may be a better approach at least:

```
allDat_10 <- subset(allDat, Expression > quantile(Expression, prob = 10/100, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Comment: You probably want `expr < quantile(...)` otherwise you'd be getting the top 90%. Check `dim(allDat_10)` to make sure you're getting the right number of rows.

Comment: check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33220693/dplyr-group-by-and-select-top-x

Answer (score 3):

Using (I fixed the sign and replaced `expr` with `Expression`)

```
subset(allDat, Expression < quantile(Expression, prob = 0.1, na.rm = TRUE))
```

may be fine; it depends on what exactly you mean by 10% of values. If you had 100 rows, do you want the result to contain 10 rows? If so, then perhaps you actually want

```
subset(allDat, Expression %in% sort(Expression)[1:round(0.1 * length(Expression))])
```

Those two approaches are not the same. The latter will return 10%~ of all the rows, while the first one may return even an empty data frame! For instance,

```
allDat <- allDat[c(1, 2, rep(3, 10)), ]
subset(allDat, Expression < quantile(Expression, prob = 0.1, na.rm = TRUE))
# [1] SampleID   Expression Gene      
# <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

Now if you replaced `<` by `<=`, the result would contain 10 rows, while `allDat` itself has 12 rows.

So, use `quantile` if you are thinking about the theoretical distribution of `Expression` and have enough data (to approximate it properly), and use `sort` if you want a fixed number of rows.

Comment: Thank you! Sorry, I had `expr` and `Expression` correct in my actual code. But yes, I'm trying to do more of the theoretical distribution approach when I say "bottom 10%"

Comment: Then indeed your approach is correct. Also, as you can see, it may matter whether you use `<` or `<=`. If you prefer `dplyr`, it looks like the question linked in a comment above contains some solutions using it.

Comment: @claudiadast, perhaps then the answer can be accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Use `dplyr` function.
I show an example of dataset `diamonds` to do the similar work.

```r
library(tidyverse)
diamonds %>% 
    top_n(depth
          ,n = -0.1*nrow(.))
#> # A tibble: 5,625 x 10
#>    carat cut       color clarity depth table price     x     y     z
#>    <dbl> <ord>     <ord> <ord>   <dbl> <dbl> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1  0.21 Premium   E     SI1      59.8    61   326  3.89  3.84  2.31
#>  2  0.23 Good      E     VS1      56.9    65   327  4.05  4.07  2.31
#>  3  0.23 Very Good H     VS1      59.4    61   338  4     4.05  2.39
#>  4  0.31 Very Good J     SI1      59.4    62   353  4.39  4.43  2.62
#>  5  0.31 Very Good J     SI1      58.1    62   353  4.44  4.47  2.59
#>  6  0.23 Very Good F     VS1      60      57   402  4     4.03  2.41
#>  7  0.23 Very Good F     VS1      59.8    57   402  4.04  4.06  2.42
#>  8  0.23 Very Good E     VS1      59.5    58   402  4.01  4.06  2.4 
#>  9  0.23 Good      F     VS1      58.2    59   402  4.06  4.08  2.37
#> 10  0.26 Good      D     VS1      58.4    63   403  4.19  4.24  2.46
#> # ... with 5,615 more rows
```

Created on 2018-11-02 by the [reprex
package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

```r
devtools::session_info()
#> Session info -------------------------------------------------------------
#>  setting  value                       
#>  version  R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)
#>  system   x86_64, darwin15.6.0        
#>  ui       X11                         
#>  language (EN)                        
#>  collate  zh_CN.UTF-8                 
#>  tz       Asia/Shanghai               
#>  date     2018-11-02
#> Packages -----------------------------------------------------------------
#>  package    * version date       source         
#>  assertthat   0.2.0   2017-04-11 CRAN (R 3.5.0) 
#>  backports    1.1.2   2017-12-13 CRAN (R 3.5.0) 
#>  base       * 3.5.1   2018-07-05 local          
#>  bindr        0.1.1   2018-03-13 CRAN (R 3.5.0) 
#>  bindrcpp   * 0.2.2   2018-03-29 CRAN (R 3.5.0) 
#>  broom        0.5.0   2018-07-17 CRAN (R 3.5.0) 
#>  cellranger   1.1.0   2016-07-27 CRAN (R 3.5.0) 
#>  cli          1.0.0   2017-11-05 CRAN (R 3.5.0) 
#>  colorspace   1.3-2   2016-12-14 CRAN (R 3.5.0) 
#>  compiler     3.5.1   2018-07-05 local          
#>  crayon       1.3.4   2017-09-16 CRAN (R 3.5.0) 
#>  datasets   * 3.5.1   2018-07-05 local          
#>  devtools     1.13.6  2018-06-27 CRAN (R 3.5.0) 
#>  digest       0.6.16  2018-08-22 cran (@0.6.16) 
#>  dplyr      * 0.7.6   2018-06-29 CRAN (R 3.5.1) 
#>  evaluate     0.11    2018-07-17 CRAN (R 3.5.0) 
#>  fansi        0.2.3   2018-05-06 CRAN (R 3.5.0) 
#>  forcats    * 0.3.0   2018-02-19 CRAN (R 3.5.0) 
#>  ggplot2    * 3.0.0   2018-07-03 CRAN (R 3.5.0) 
#>  glue         1.3.0   2018-07-17 CRAN (R 3.5.0) 
#>  graphics   * 3.5.1   2018-07-05 local          
#>  grDevices  * 3.5.1   2018-07-05 local          
#>  grid         3.5.1   2018-07-05 local          
#>  gtable       0.2.0   2016-02-26 CRAN (R 3.5.0) 
#>  haven        1.1.2   2018-06-27 CRAN (R 3.5.0) 
#>  hms          0.4.2   2018-03-10 CRAN (R 3.5.0) 
#>  htmltools    0.3.6   2017-04-28 CRAN (R 3.5.0) 
#>  httr         1.3.1   2017-08-20 CRAN (R 3.5.0) 
#>  jsonlite     1.5     2017-06-01 CRAN (R 3.5.0) 
#>  knitr        1.20    2018-02-20 CRAN (R 3.5.0) 
#>  lattice      0.20-35 2017-03-25 CRAN (R 3.5.1) 
#>  lazyeval     0.2.1   2017-10-29 CRAN (R 3.5.0) 
#>  lubridate    1.7.4   2018-04-11 CRAN (R 3.5.0) 
#>  magrittr     1.5     2014-11-22 CRAN (R 3.5.0) 
#>  memoise      1.1.0   2017-04-21 CRAN (R 3.5.0) 
#>  methods    * 3.5.1   2018-07-05 local          
#>  modelr       0.1.2   2018-05-11 CRAN (R 3.5.0) 
#>  munsell      0.5.0   2018-06-12 CRAN (R 3.5.0) 
#>  nlme         3.1-137 2018-04-07 CRAN (R 3.5.1) 
#>  pillar       1.3.0   2018-07-14 CRAN (R 3.5.0) 
#>  pkgconfig    2.0.1   2017-03-21 CRAN (R 3.5.0) 
#>  plyr         1.8.4   2016-06-08 CRAN (R 3.5.0) 
#>  purrr      * 0.2.5   2018-05-29 CRAN (R 3.5.0) 
#>  R6           2.3.0   2018-10-04 cran (@2.3.0)  
#>  Rcpp         0.12.19 2018-10-01 cran (@0.12.19)
#>  readr      * 1.1.1   2017-05-16 CRAN (R 3.5.0) 
#>  readxl       1.1.0   2018-04-20 CRAN (R 3.5.0) 
#>  rlang        0.2.2   2018-08-16 cran (@0.2.2)  
#>  rmarkdown    1.10    2018-06-11 CRAN (R 3.5.0) 
#>  rprojroot    1.3-2   2018-01-03 CRAN (R 3.5.0) 
#>  rvest        0.3.2   2016-06-17 CRAN (R 3.5.0) 
#>  scales       1.0.0   2018-08-09 CRAN (R 3.5.0) 
#>  stats      * 3.5.1   2018-07-05 local          
#>  stringi      1.2.4   2018-07-20 CRAN (R 3.5.0) 
#>  stringr    * 1.3.1   2018-05-10 CRAN (R 3.5.0) 
#>  tibble     * 1.4.2   2018-01-22 CRAN (R 3.5.0) 
#>  tidyr      * 0.8.1   2018-05-18 CRAN (R 3.5.0) 
#>  tidyselect   0.2.5   2018-10-11 cran (@0.2.5)  
#>  tidyverse  * 1.2.1   2017-11-14 CRAN (R 3.5.0) 
#>  tools        3.5.1   2018-07-05 local          
#>  utf8         1.1.4   2018-05-24 CRAN (R 3.5.0) 
#>  utils      * 3.5.1   2018-07-05 local          
#>  withr        2.1.2   2018-03-15 CRAN (R 3.5.0) 
#>  xml2         1.2.0   2018-01-24 CRAN (R 3.5.0) 
#>  yaml         2.2.0   2018-07-25 CRAN (R 3.5.0)
```