# Consider grouping for a column and selecting rows based on other columns in R

Tags: r, grouping

My data is dataframe(fpo):

```
     damIDpoG4 damSirepoG4 damGpoG4 damPhenpoG4 damTBVpoG4 damGBVpoG4
[1,]    450622      430878        4    5.540501   4.260957   3.422568
[2,]    450623      430878        4    3.046358   4.169094   3.528200
[3,]    450625      430878        4    4.515801   4.543196   3.843761
....
[50,]    450626      470878        4    4.798896   4.501067   3.875034
[51,]    450630      470878        4    4.282659   4.388037   3.830042
[52,]    450632      470878        4    3.553223   4.086484   3.571130
```

I want to select n number (for example 12) from **damIDpoG4** for per similar group of **damSirepoG4** according to MAX  and or 20%  **damGBVpoG4**. 
 **damSirepoG4** contain 250 groups of identical numbers
I try:

```
fpo %>% group_by(fpo[,2]) %>% sample_n(12)
```

but my answer is not correct.  I could not consider max or percent for dplyr
thanks for attention

Answer (score 1):

We need to pass the column name in `group_by` (assuming that 'fpo' is `data.frame/tbl_df` and not a `matrix`)

```
fpo %>% 
    group_by(damSirepoG4) %>%
    sample_n(12)
```

Comment: This is to thank you for devoting your time to answering my question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33220693/dplyr-group-by-and-select-top-x was very good answer